# How to test a function outside the main class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'd like to test a `main` function that exists outside a class. This main function calls two methods from the class. Here is the script I want to test:

```py
class Class:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def fun1(self, arg1):
        ...
    
    def fun2(self, arg2):
        ...
    
def main(arg1, arg2):
    myclass = Class()
    call1 = myclass.fun1(arg1)
    call2 = myclass.fun2(arg2)
```

Here is my try when I test it:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

class TestClass(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.foo = 1

    def test_fun1(self):
        ...
    
    def test_fun2(self):
        ...
    
class TestMain(TestClass):
    def test_main(self):
        # mocking fun1 & fun2 here?
```

How can I test the `main` function which calls the two functions `fun1` and `fun2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can `patch` the `Class` and its `fun1` and `fun2` methods.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
class Class:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def fun1(self, arg1):
        pass

    def fun2(self, arg2):
        pass


def main(arg1, arg2):
    myclass = Class()
    call1 = myclass.fun1(arg1)
    call2 = myclass.fun2(arg2)
    print(call1, call2)
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from main import main


class TestMain(TestCase):
    @patch('main.Class')
    def test_main(self, mock_Class):
        instance = mock_Class.return_value
        instance.fun1.return_value = 'r1'
        instance.fun2.return_value = 'r2'
        main('a', 'b')
        instance.fun1.assert_called_once_with('a')
        instance.fun2.assert_called_once_with('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Test result:

```sh
test_main (__main__.TestMain) ... r1 r2
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```